# MongoDB Query Combined and & or

Tags: sql, mongodb

This SQL query:

```
SELECT name
FROM user 
WHERE user.provider = "google" or user.email="email@example.com"
```

have equivalent mongodb query:

```
db.user.find({
    "$or": [{
        "user.provider": "google"
    }, {
        "user.email": "email@example.com"
    }]
}, {
    "name": 1
});
```

How about this one?

```
SELECT name
FROM user 
WHERE (user.provider = "google" and user.id="1") or user.email="email@example.com"
```

What is the equivalent of the above SQL to mongo? Is it possible to have combined and & or in mongo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can combine them. You should be able to do:

```
"$or":[
  {"$and": [{"user.provider": "google"}, {"user.id": "1"}] },
  { "user.email" : "email@example.com" }
]
```